# Stripe gem - Discover, Diners Club and JCB cards - Your card is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using [stripe gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) and I am trying to add a credit card with the following code as the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) suggests:

```
Stripe::Token.create(
  :card => {
    :number => "4242424242424242",
    :exp_month => 1,
    :exp_year => 2017,
    :cvc => "314"
  },
)
```

I tried all of the test card numbers from [this page of stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) and it seems it doesn't work for the **diners club**, **discover** and **JCB**.

The error I am getting from stripe is `Stripe::CardError: Your card is not supported` when I am using one of the above cards, but it works fine with visa, mastercard and american express. Why is this happening? Should I enable the cards from somewhere on the stripe panel or should I pass some extra parameter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only [U.S. businesses](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe) can accept Diners Club, Discover and JCB. I think you have a non-US stripe account.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-currencies-does-stripe-support - "JCB, Discover, and Diners Club cards can only be charged in United States Dollars.". I think the limitation is still there.

Comment: Thanks. For example for New Zealand, support confirmed for me that only Visa, MasterCard and American Express are supported.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this issue too earlier today, support told me that apparently Japanese Stripe account holders can only use Visa, Mastercard and AMEX, but not JCB, Discover or Dinner (even though the documentation clearly contradicts this statement by saying that users in Japan ("Users in 日本" as they write there) can use all options).

And I find this rather mind blowing, it's like if you were a major supplier to book stores all over the world, and you'd not allow any American stores to buy comics in English or Spanish from you because you can only sell them comics in Chinese and Arabic.
Meanwhile you'd allow Japanese stores to buy comics in every language in existence.

JCB is a Japanese credit card firm, and lots of our customers only have a JCB card.
So being unable to accept that is rather weird to me.